# Retraction of Shrinking Wedge of Circles or Hawaiian Earrings

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am trying to understand the example 1.25 of Hatcher Book about the Srinking Wdge of Circle.

Consider the subspace $X$ of  $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is the union of the circles $C_n$ of radius $\frac{1}{n}$ and center $\left(\frac{1}{n},0\right)$ for $ n = 1,2,3,\ldots $.

I have two question: why such retraction deffined by Hatcher exists?
He define a family of retraction $r_n : X \to C_n$ collapsing all $C_i$'s except $C_n$ to the origin. I try to explicity this retraction, but I dont have sucess. Can anyone help me? Is possible given a explicy retraction for this?

If such retraction exist's, why this cannot be retract to a point, Since all $n-1$ circles are collapsed to the origin?

This retraction seems hard to believe. Since if we fix a $C_n$ and collapse all the other circles to the origin, I can't see what's stopping me from also collapsing the $C_n$ to the origin.

Comment: One *could* retract all the circles to the origin. Without more context from you, one can only guess that his goal in considering the retractions $r_n$ has something to do with why he leaves out the circle $C_n$ and just collapses the others to the origin.

Comment: My question is why such retract exists, He consider this retraction and use the injective of  induced homomorphism of inclusion $C_n \hookrightarrow X$ to show that  the induced homomorphism of such retraction is surjective.

Comment: I just responded an hour ago and you did not acknowledge. However there is no problem defining the $r_n.$ It is the identity map on $C_n$ and the constant map on all other circles, mapping them to the origin.

Comment: Note that each $C_n$ is closed (in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and therefore in $X$) and so is $\bigcup_{k \ge n} C_k$ since it is the intersection of $X$ with the closed disk whose boundary is $C_n$. Now use pasting lemma.

Comment: It sounds like you might be confusing retractions with *deformation retractions*.  Hatcher is only claiming there is a retraction here, not a deformation retraction.